# Can't refresh questions after going back to them in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Steps to reproduce:

- Find a question that has a link to another question
- Click the link
- Press the "back" button on your phone to go back to the original question
- Try (and fail) to refresh

It's quite common to see a meta post or something, follow a bunch of cross-references, go back, and want to see any new updates, so could this be fixed?

Comment: Curiously, this appears to only affect _questions_, but not _answers_. Affects 1.0.30.

Comment: ... I wondered why this was happening. Kudos to you for the repro steps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in version 1.0.31, we were setting up the pull-to-refresh controller in the activity's `onCreate`, which meant if you left the page and came back to it while it was still in memory you would lose the controller. Excellent catch!